# How to draw polyline on GoogleMap that follows path of the pegman?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I'm working on creating a simple game in HTML and JavaScript using the GoogleMaps API. The code I have as of now displays the map view on the left side of the screen and street view on the right side of the screen. As you move the arrow keys around, the pegman (that's the little guy that moves around the streets in GoogleMaps) rotates and moves forward and back according to the key pressed (this is a default GoogleMaps feature). What I'm trying to do is add a constantly updating polyline that shows everywhere the Pegman has visited. I've been referring to the documentation [here][1] and [here][2]. 
HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="map_with_markers.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="pegman_lines.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>A to B</h3>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="pano"></div>
    <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOURAPIKEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>


  [1]: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview?hl=nl#StreetViewEvents
  [2]:
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PolylineOptions

JavaScript code:

```
    var poly;
    var map;
  function initMap() {
        var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
            center: {lat: 30.565244, lng: -97.671010},
            zoom: 14
        });

        var txstate = {lat: 30.569858, lng: -97.655918};
        var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
            document.getElementById('pano'), {
              position: txstate,
              pov: {
                heading: 34,
                pitch: 10
              }
            });
        map.setStreetView(panorama);

       poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
          strokeColor: '#000000',
          strokeOpacity: 1.0,
          strokeWeight: 3
        });
        poly.setMap(map);

        // Add a listener for the click event
        map.addListener('position_change', addLatLng);
      }
      // Handles click events on a map, and adds a new point to the Polyline.
      function addLatLng(event) {
        var path = poly.getPath();

        // Because path is an MVCArray, we can simply append a new coordinate
        // and it will automatically appear.
        path.push(event.latLng);

        //point A
        //hard-coded as Texas State University right now
        var image = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/73/Farm-Fresh_star.png"; //STAR

        var pointA = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: {lat: 30.567989, lng: -97.655153}, 
            map: map,
            title: 'tx state',
            icon: image,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
        });
        var contentString_A = '<h5>texas state university at round rock</h5>';
        var infowindow_A = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString_A
        });
        function info_A(){
            infowindow_A.open(map, pointA);
        }


        //point B
        //hard-coded as H-E-B right now
        var pointB = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: {lat: 30.560619, lng: -97.688338}, 
            map: map,
            title: 'heb',
            icon: image,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
        });
        var contentString_B = '<h5>h-e-b</h5>';
        var infowindow_B = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString_B
        });
        function info_B(){
            infowindow_B.open(map, pointB);
        }



        pointA.addListener('click', info_A);
        pointB.addListener('click', info_B);

        function toggleBounce() {
          if (marker.getAnimation() !== null) {
            marker.setAnimation(null);
          } else {
            marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
          }
        }

      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the `addLatLng()` function when the `panorama` "pano_changed" event is triggered, with the position of the new panorama:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(panorama, 'pano_changed', function(){
  addLatLng({latLng:panorama.getPosition()});
}):
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/uxwb7xz9/2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var poly;
var map;
var pointA;
var pointB;

function initMap() {
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
    map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
      center: {
        lat: 30.565244,
        lng: -97.671010
      },
      zoom: 14
    });

    var txstate = {
      lat: 30.569858,
      lng: -97.655918
    };
    var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
      document.getElementById('pano'), {
        position: txstate,
        pov: {
          heading: 34,
          pitch: 10
        }
      });
    google.maps.event.addListener(panorama, 'pano_changed', function() {
      addLatLng({
        latLng: panorama.getPosition()
      });
      if (!map.getBounds().contains(panorama.getPosition())) {
        map.setCenter(panorama.getPosition());
      }
    })
    map.setStreetView(panorama);

    poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
      strokeColor: '#000000',
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 3
    });
    poly.setMap(map);

    // Add a listener for the click event
    map.addListener('position_change', addLatLng);
  }
  // Handles click events on a map, and adds a new point to the Polyline.

function addLatLng(event) {
  var path = poly.getPath();

  // Because path is an MVCArray, we can simply append a new coordinate
  // and it will automatically appear.
  path.push(event.latLng);

  //point A
  //hard-coded as Texas State University right now
  var image = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/73/Farm-Fresh_star.png"; //STAR
  if (!pointA) {
    pointA = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {
        lat: 30.567989,
        lng: -97.655153
      },
      map: map,
      title: 'tx state',
      icon: image,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });
    var contentString_A = '<h5>texas state university at round rock</h5>';
    var infowindow_A = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString_A
    });
    pointA.addListener('click', info_A);

  }

  function info_A() {
    infowindow_A.open(map, pointA);
  }

  //point B
  //hard-coded as H-E-B right now
  if (!pointB) {
    var pointB = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {
        lat: 30.560619,
        lng: -97.688338
      },
      map: map,
      title: 'heb',
      icon: image,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });
    var contentString_B = '<h5>h-e-b</h5>';
    var infowindow_B = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString_B
    });
    pointB.addListener('click', info_B);
  }

  function info_B() {
    infowindow_B.open(map, pointB);
  }

  function toggleBounce() {
    if (marker.getAnimation() !== null) {
      marker.setAnimation(null);
    } else {
      marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
    }
  }

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 45%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
#pano {
  height: 100%;
  width: 45%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<h3>A to B</h3>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="pano"></div>
```